# Gulp gulp-postcss ENOENT: no such file or directory Can not change scss to css

Tags: css, docker, flask, gulp, tailwind-css

I got an error when creating a gulp build with tailwind templates, in the file path '/pmp
server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/src/assets/scss/'.
there is a tailwind.scss file and gulp-postcss (so I think) tries to find the .css file. The paths are definitely good. This code works on windows and does not work on linux conctretely on ubuntu docker image

**ERROR**

```
`> [17/21] RUN gulp build --verbose:
2.177 [07:36:40] Using gulpfile /pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/gulpfile.js
2.178 [07:36:40] Starting 'build'...
2.180 [07:36:40] Starting 'clean:packageLock'...
2.183 [07:36:40] Finished 'clean:packageLock' after 3.29 ms
2.184 [07:36:40] Starting 'clean:dist'...
2.189 [07:36:40] Finished 'clean:dist' after 4.8 ms
2.189 [07:36:40] Starting 'copy:all'...
2.778 [07:36:41] Finished 'copy:all' after 589 ms
2.778 [07:36:41] Starting 'copy:libs'...
7.253 [07:36:45] Finished 'copy:libs' after 4.47 s
7.253 [07:36:45] Starting 'fileinclude'...
7.364 [07:36:45] Finished 'fileinclude' after 111 ms
7.364 [07:36:45] Starting 'scss'...
7.668 Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
7.668   npx browserslist@latest --update-db
7.668   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
7.829 [07:36:46] 'scss' errored after 465 ms
7.829 [07:36:46] Error in plugin "gulp-postcss"
7.829 Message:
7.829     ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/src/assets/scss/tailwind.css'
7.829 Details:
7.829     errno: -2
7.829     syscall: stat
7.829     code: ENOENT
7.829     path: /pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/src/assets/scss/tailwind.css
7.829     fileName: /pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/src/assets/scss/tailwind.css
7.829     domainEmitter: [object Object]
7.829     domainThrown: false
7.829     at LazyResult.async (/pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:30)
7.829     at LazyResult.then (/pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:206:17)7.829     at LazyResult.async (/pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:30)
7.829     at LazyResult.then (/pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:206:17)
7.830 [07:36:46] 'build' errored after 5.65 s

Dockerfile_dev:32`
```

---

**CODE FOR SCCS IN GULPFILE**

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {
    // generate tailwind  
    return gulp
        .src([paths.src.scss.main, '!' + paths.src.scss.icon])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))

        .pipe(postcss([
            tailwindcss(paths.config.tailwind),
            autoprefixer()
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.css.dir))
        // .pipe(cssnano({ svgo: false }))
        .on("data", function (file) {
            const buferFile = new cleanCSS(cssOptions).minify(file.contents);
            return (file.contents = Buffer.from(buferFile.styles));
        })
        .pipe(
            rename({
                suffix: ".min"
            })
        )
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.css.dir));
});
```

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PMP-SERVER-ENV DEV

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3.10 \
    python3-pip

RUN pip3 install setuptools
RUN pip3 install pipenv

# Install Node.js and npm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm

# Install gulp globally
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
RUN npm install --global yarn

RUN mkdir -p pmp-server
COPY . pmp-server/

WORKDIR pmp-server/resources/gui_template/Techwind_v1.6.0/HTML
RUN yarn install
RUN gulp build --verbose

WORKDIR /pmp-server
RUN pipenv sync

# Install version of libssl required by couchbase python libraries
RUN wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb

EXPOSE 5000

CMD /bin/bash
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

probowalem zmieniac sciezki, troche zmieniac kod tworzacy css z scss nic to nie dało